# Running npm install .nvmrc gets populated with seemingly random node version

Tags: node.js, git, intellij-idea, nvm, husky

Running `npm install` from my project creates an `.nvmrc` file under **./node_modules/sockjs-client/.nvmrc** which points to **6.14.2**. Some information about my local installation:

- `nvm --version`: 0.34.0
- `npm --version`: 6.4.1
- `node --version`: v11.3.0
- `nvm ls`

  ->      v11.3.0
     v12.10.0
       system
  default -> 11.3.0 (-> v11.3.0)
  node -> stable (-> v12.10.0) (default)
  stable -> 12.10 (-> v12.10.0) (default)
  iojs -> N/A (default)
  unstable -> N/A (default)
  lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
  lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
  lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
  lts/carbon -> v8.16.1 (-> N/A)
  lts/dubnium -> v10.16.3 (-> N/A)

The problem concerns my husky git hooks and is the following:
When I am trying to commit from the command line, I have no issue whatsoever. The node version is appropriately identified and I can successfully commit.

From other UI environments though (IntelliJ, SmartGit) the git hooks fail with the following:

```
0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: lasfasdf husky > pre-commit (node v8.11.4) lint-staged requires at least version 8.12.0 of Node, please upgrade husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

When I delete the `node_modules` folder and the `.nvmrc` file included in the subfolder I can successfully commit again through IntelliJ and SmartGit.
My IntelliJ config for node is the following:
[image]

My hypothesis is the IntelliJ and SmartGit use the nvm version specified in this erroneously populated `.nvmrc` file. I'm not very familiar with node version management - or node itself as a matter of fact - so I might ask the following in order to reason about this inconsistency:

- How is the `.nvmrc` file created? In which stage and what defines its contents?
- Is there some other way to identify all available node versions on my machine apart from `nvm ls` - I am wondering if some obsolete node version drives the population of the `.nvmrc` with this super old **6.14.2** version.

EDIT:
This is the list of my Node interpreters
[image]

This is the contents of my PATH as this is resolved in IntelliJ

```
PATH=/home/username/.npm-global/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ doesn't create any .nvmrc file.
What's your OS?

I'd recommend you to check PATH environment variable in IDE:

- Open "Settings | Tools | Terminal"
- Open "Environment Variables" dialog
- Find PATH in the list of inherited system environment variables. How will which node be resolved according to it?

Then, please

- Open "Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM"
- Expand "Node.js interpreters" drop-down list and attach a screenshot of it.

Comment: Thanks @Oksana. I updated my question with the info you requested.

Comment: Thanks! The issue here is that `node` from `PATH` is resolved as `/usr/bin/node` (which is 8.11.4). Please try workarounds from this IntelliJ IDEA issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589